# Specifying true/false values for a Vuetify v-checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using the Vuetify component `v-checkbox`.

I want to specify specific values for the true/false states of the checkbox.

Looking at the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls) it looks like I can do this using the `true-value` & `false-value` props.

```
<v-checkbox
    v-else-if="input.type == 'checkbox'"
    false-value="0"
    true-value="1"
    input-value="input.val"
    :error-messages="form.errors[field]"
>
    <template #label>@{{ input.hint }}</template>
</v-checkbox>
```

However using the example above does not submit a value of `1` when the checkbox is checked. The checkbox submits `0` regardless of whether the checkbox is checked or not.

**What do I need to do to properly set the `true-value` to `1`?**

Comment: Vuetify documentation says the `input-value` prop is supposed to be `The v-model bound value`

Comment: The problem is that you used `input-value` instead of `:input-value` (notice `:`). `input-value` property exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `v-model` directive instead of `input-value` prop like :

```
<v-checkbox
     v-else-if="input.type == 'checkbox'"
     false-value="0"
      true-value="1"
     v-model="input.val"
    :error-messages="form.errors[field]"
                            >
    <template #label>@{{ input.hint }}</template>
</v-checkbox>
```

check this **[`code example`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WqKyxm?&editable=true&editors=101)**